Mapbox Maps Flutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mapbox_maps_flutter/mapbox_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() async {
  final String accessToken = await loadMapboxAccessToken();
  final initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(-74.0060, 40.7128),
    zoom: 13.0,
  );

  runApp(MyApp(accessToken: accessToken, initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String accessToken;
  final CameraPosition initialCameraPosition;

  const MyApp({super.key, required this.accessToken, required this.initialCameraPosition});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Mapbox Map Demo'),
        ),
        body: MapboxMap(
          accessToken: accessToken,
          initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<String> loadMapboxAccessToken() async {
  return "sk.eyJ1IjoibWFoYXdpeWFydGEiLCJhIjoiY2x5bnZjMDM0MDJybjJpc2xqczBqazU3YSJ9.zZIqIhzhMsH_kSUPZ0zIAQ"; // Replace with your actual token (avoid this in production)
}

So this is my code, this code show errors =
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\ancam\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\mapbox_maps_flutter-2.1.0\android\build.gradle' line: 21

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':mapbox_maps_flutter'.



SDK Registry token is null. See README.md for more information.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':mapbox_maps_flutter'.


Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':mapbox_maps_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':mapbox_maps_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```
Can you guys please help me solve this problem, i have tried to solving this for about 1 hour, thanks guys
